# cargo run не выводит сообщение в консоль

Tags: rust

Бьюсь уже второй день. Не работает. Программа компилируется, но сообщение не выводит. Самая банальщина:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Запускаю командой `cargo run`. И в консоли вижу это:

```
C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust>cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target\debug\hello-rust.exe`

C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust>
```

То есть я не вижу надписи `Hello, world!`. На другом компьютере ставил, все завелось с 1 раза. На всякий случай файл `cargo.toml`.

```rb
[package]
name = "hello-rust"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Ramark <xxxxxx@mail.ru>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

Процесс установки такой: сначала накатил средства сборки *C++* из *BuildTools,*
затем ставил *Rust.* Платформа *Windows* 10. Пробовал переустанавливать раст, не помогло. Подскажите, куда копать?

Upd. 1
Не работает именно команда cargo run Если попробовать так

```
C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust\src>rustc main.rs 
C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust\src>.\main.exe 
Hello, world!
C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust\src>
```

то как видно работает Если попробовать запустить напрямую

```
 C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust>target\debug\hello-rust.exe 
Hello, world!
```

То тоже работает. А вот cargo run не выводит

Comment: На другом компьютере тоже _Windows_ 10?  Удалять `target` пробовали?

Comment: Не понял где удалить ```target```. Не работает именно команда cargo run
Если попробовать так
```
C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust\src>rustc main.rs

C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust\src>.\main.exe
Hello, world!

C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust\src>
```
то как видно работает
Если попробовать запустить напрямую
```
C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust>target\debug\hello-rust.exe
Hello, world!
```
То тоже все работает. А вот cargo run не работает

Comment: Директорию `target` в корне проекта.  И вы не ответили на мой первый вопрос.

Comment: Да, на другом компе тоже win 10. Папку ```target``` удалил. Результат
C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust>cargo run
   Compiling hello-rust v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.97s
     Running `target\debug\hello-rust.exe`

C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust>

Напрямую запускается
C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust>target\debug\hello-rust.exe
Hello, world!

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что проблема действительно в этом, но возможно, что это
пробемы с CRLF или буферизацией.  Попробуйте:

```rust
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    print!("Hello, world!\r\n");
    std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Пишет что не знает метода flush ```error[E0599]: no method named `flush` found for type `std::io::Stdout` in the current scope```

Comment: @ДмитрийЛарин  Привёл более полный код.

Comment: Все так же ```C:/Users/Ramark/.cargo/bin/cargo.exe run --color=always
   Compiling hello-rust v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Ramark\RustProjects\hello-rust)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.97s
     Running `target\debug\hello-rust.exe`

Process finished with exit code 0
```
Напрямую запускается

Comment: Увы, у меня пока больше идей нет.